# Dockerized selenium browser cannot access Capybara test url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, docker, capybara

I am trying to run Ruby on Rails feature tests on dockerized selenium standalone firefox browser.
It seems like I am having issues with networking because the selenium instance can't connect
to the url started by Capybara.

Here's my sample `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
ff:
  image: selenium/standalone-firefox:2.48.2
  container_name: firefox-browser
web:
  build: .
  container_name: my-app
  volumes:
    - ".:/home/ubuntu/my-app"
  command: /bin/bash -l scripts/docker-start-tests.sh
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
```

And I start docker-compose with networking enabled:

```
docker-compose --x-networking up
```

The test script runs an rspec command like this

```
rspec ./spec/features/login_spec.rb:43
```

For docker tests I have enabled remote driver for Capybara:

```
Capybara.register_driver :docker_firefox do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {
    browser: :remote,
    url: "#{ENV['FF_URL']}/wd/hub",
    desired_capabilities: Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox
  })
end
```

And finally I call the test like this:

```
unless ENV['FF_URL'].nil?
  Capybara.current_driver = :docker_firefox
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :docker_firefox

  Capybara.app_host = "http://my-app:56555"
  Capybara.server_port = "56555"
  # Capybara.server_host = "my-app"
end

visit root_path
save_and_open_screenshot
click_link "Sign in"
...
```

I can tail browser container logs and I see that selenium receives commands from Capybara.
The problem is that it cannot connect to the url provided, which I can confirm with the screenshot.

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at my-app:56555

To better understand the problem, I started the rails app and I tried to access it from the selenium
container. I notice that I can only access the app from the selenium container if I start the rails app with an ip binding.

```
rails s Puma -b 0.0.0.0
```

This looks like a networking problem, but I can't figure out a solution.

How can I make the selenium container access the rails app running Rspec feature tests with Capybara?

```
capybara (2.6.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.48.1)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The server thread rails runs the test app in binds to Capybara.server_host (127.0.0.1 by default)  - you can try changing that to whatever ip interface the docker container can talk back to your machine on - maybe 0.0.0.0

Comment: @TomWalpole Are you referring to `Capybara.app_host`? I parse the assigned ip for the container running rails and I pass it to app_host. Still, I can't access it from the selenium container.

Comment: No -- Capybara.app_host is used to build addresses the browser is told to visit, Capybara.server_host sets the ip the test app listens on for connections from the browser

Comment: Oh sorry. I noticed soon after I submitted my comment. You are right, adding server_host fixed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem -- I'll add it as an answer for you to accept

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The server thread rails runs the test app in binds to the Capybara.server_host interface (127.0.0.1 by default) - You can change that to whatever ip interface the docker container can talk back to your machine on - in your case possibly

```
Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0' # bind to all interfaces
```