# Rails system test with capybara and headless selenium browser in Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, docker, automated-tests, integration-testing

TL;DR: Any idea about how to properly configure capybara to be able to drive a remote selenium browser in a docker container with default Rails minitest system test?

I'm running Rails in a dockerized env..
Now I want to start some "system tests" but since I'm running inside Docker I come up with some issues.

I'm using the default test suite (minitest?) with `capybara` and `selenium-webdriver` gems.

I've already installed the `chromedriver` packet in the container using the following:

```
RUN apt-get install -y chromedriver \
  && ln -s /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/local/bin
```

But running `rails test:system` outputs the following error `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: Unable to find chromedriver.`

In fact I don't know if *chrome* itself is installed or not?

`which chrome` outputs nothing.

`which chromium` outputs `/usr/bin/chromium`.

I also tried with `xvfb` without success.

So (since I had no clue) I tried to go further and actually go with a dockerized system test environment as well.

I found some Docker images from selenium. So I ran among my rails and database containers a `selenium-standalone-chrome` container (the actual [docker-compose.yml I'm using is here](https://gist.github.com/sanjibukai/1a97fd67183bef2a715bfda0380b0f43))

Then I found some useful information about the configuration to be done to let capybara driver the *remote* selenium browser.

 All the examples I found on internet use rspec, but since I'm using the default minispec I tried to adapt the capybara driver to minispec but I had some doubt about how to do it and where to put the configuration.

For system tests I guessed that the best location is the file `application_system_test_case.rb`. Also I found and I tried many different capybara configurations and I end up with the following which seems to be the most complete [(available here)](https://gist.github.com/sanjibukai/bfc5117221a006d4e6829e3e5a662388)

At that moment the test seems to perform well since I have no error but it always fails.

It fails regardless of making a call to the driver configuration (the `setup_remote` method where I defined the server host and port) before the tests case.

With or without the call I got the *"site can't be reached"* error ([here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZMUy.png))

 Here is [the test file I used](https://gist.github.com/sanjibukai/c677a8e2db53d44fd6558b8b90a9dfb8). (Testing some react dynamic display)

However I can access to the selenium container with the given URL from the browser from my host machine. And both containers sees each others. *I did some ping from within the containers shell.*

The following SO questions being helpful don't work for me:

[Dockerized selenium browser cannot access Capybara test url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35081382/dockerized-selenium-browser-cannot-access-capybara-test-url)

[How can I run headless browser system tests in Rails 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813014/how-can-i-run-headless-browser-system-tests-in-rails-5-1)

Any idea about how to properly configure capybara to be able to drive a remote selenium browser in a docker container with default Rails minitest system test?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi again.. The default address of the remote selenium seems to be an address like `http://172.18.0.2:4444/wd/hub/`. But when I access this URL from the host using a browser it redirects to the following page `http://172.18.0.2:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html`. So I tried to put this URL in the register driver portion. This time I got some other selenium errors. But the most important thing is that among the console errros I also got some *"System Info"* which displays the same metadata displayed by the selenium site which means that the connection rails->selenium seems to work well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to override the host method so Capybara uses the container's IP address. Check out this post: https://medium.com/@pacuna/using-rails-5-1-system-tests-with-docker-a90c52ed0648

Comment: I pass from [this code](https://gist.github.com/sanjibukai/bfc5117221a006d4e6829e3e5a662388) to this [much simpler code](https://gist.github.com/sanjibukai/a3d9aa38e0b0ae05368a7999fb813b4b), thank you..